Using buildroot inside comtainer on mounted volume failing with access denied. Why?
Here is a simple dockerfile to cross build:
FROM debian:buster

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN useradd -u 501 -ms /bin/bash build
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    sudo \
    sed \
    wget \
    cpio \
    unzip \
    rsync \
    bc \
    bison \
    flex \
    libssl-dev \
    make \
    kmod \
    libc6-dev \
    libncurses5-dev \
    crossbuild-essential-armhf \
    crossbuild-essential-arm64

WORKDIR /home/build
USER build
VOLUME ["/home/build"]

and script I'm running:
# Defaults
IMAGE_NAME=${IMAGE_NAME:-"linux_builder"}
ARCH=${ARCH:-"arm"}
CORES=${CORES:-0}
KERNEL=${KERNEL:-"kernel7"}
CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE:-"arm-linux-gnueabihf-"}
VOLUME="$(pwd)/fs"

# Run builder environment
podman run --rm \
    --device /dev/fuse \
    --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
    --name $IMAGE_NAME \
    -v $VOLUME:"/home/build/fs" \
    -e ARCH=$ARCH \
    -e KERNEL=$KERNEL \
    -e CROSS_COMPILE=$CROSS_COMPILE \
    -it \
    $IMAGE_NAME \
    bash $@

When I checkout buildroot into home directory it compiles withour any problem.
But if I use mounted directory instead I get weird error:
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c pkgconf '/home/build/buildroot/output/host/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c pkgconf /home/build/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkgconf
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/build/fs/buildroot/output/build/host-pkgconf-1.6.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/build/fs/buildroot/output/build/host-pkgconf-1.6.3'
/usr/bin/install -m 0755 -D package/pkgconf/pkg-config.in /home/build/fs/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config
/bin/sed -i -e 's,@STAGING_SUBDIR@,arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot,g' /home/build/fs/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config
/bin/sed: couldn't open temporary file /home/build/fs/buildroot/output/host/bin/sedWes6rs: Permission denied
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:300: /home/build/fs/buildroot/output/build/host-pkgconf-1.6.3/.stamp_host_installed] Error 4

The same problem is when running as root.
Any idea what is going on?
Thanks for help!

You're setting up uid 501 as user build in the container.
That user don't have access to the files you're mounting into the container, that's why you see sed failing to create files.
For a rootless build, uid 0 in the container is mapped to your host user.
Either remove USER build, override it with --user 0:0, change the host's files to match or uidmap.
But beware, idmapping won't help if the uids still end up mismatching.
For your example in the question, id will not match the directory below and return:
uid=501(build) gid=1000(build) groups=1000(build)

On SELinux systems you can either have podman relabel the shared files (add Z -v $VOLUME:"/home/build/fs:Z")
or disable label separation (--security-opt label=disable)
Output from ls -lanZ fs in container:
drwxr-xr-x. 2 0    unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0  39 Aug 15 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 501 1000 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 67 Aug 15 15:46 ..
[...]

See the podman troubleshooting guide for more info.

I can't create user with uid 0.
Anyway It's not the case here.
Tried:

run as root
--userns keep-id
--userns keep-id:uid=501,gid=501.
It's something different.


Run as root inside the container (instead of 501) you'd use --user 0:0.
I don't have your buildroot but I could build and launch the container rootless. I had no problems writing files from it. As I use selinux I also had to disable labels (--security-opt=label=disable) or use :z
